# Calculating expected value of a pareto distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Suppose that you have a Pareto product distribution function defined by:

$$
f(x;k;\theta)= \begin{cases}
\frac{k\theta^k}{x^{k+1}}  & x \ge\theta \\
0 & x \lt \theta
\end{cases}
$$

How would one go about deriving the expression used to calculate the expected value $E[X]$?

I understand that in general the expected value can be calculated for any generic product distribution function $f(x)$ by the following integral:

$$E[X]=\int^\infty_{-\infty} x f(x)dx$$

Does the presence of multiple parameters change this at all? I'm not sure how to set up this integral properly using the above for $f(x; k; \theta)$.

Comment: The mean of $X$ will involve the parameters  $\theta$ and $k$. Your integral is correct, all you need to do is use our particular $f(x)$ and evaluate the integral. Note that the parameters $\theta$ and $k$ are positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it makes no difference: your expectation will just be a function of $\theta$ and $k$, viz.
$$ E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x;k;\theta) \, dx = \int_{\theta}^{\infty} \frac{k\theta^k}{x^k} \, dx = \frac{k\theta}{k-1}, $$
provided $k>1$. (In other words, the other two arguments to $f$ are just parameters: $x$ is the thing in the probability space you're integrating over.)

Comment: can you please explain how you take care of the case that $k=1$? As in, how do you rigorously prove that $E(X)=\infty$ in that case?

Comment: $\int_{\theta}^{\infty} \frac{\theta}{x} \, dx = \lim_{M \to \infty} \int_{\theta}^M \frac{\theta}{x} \, dx = \lim_{M \to \infty} \theta(\log{M}-\log{\theta}) = \infty $?

Comment: I'm working on a Pareto problem where instead of finding the expected value of $X$, we find the expected value of $Y$, which is based on $X$. $Y$ is a mixed distribution in this case, and I'm not sure how to take care of a few of the cases. Could you please take a look and offer some assistance? Thank you! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524217/expectation-of-induced-distribution